# replication error involving ignore-db

Tags: replication

I have simple master/slave replication set up between two servers.  The master has several DB's I wish not to replicate at this time, in fact there is only DB I am trying to replicate.  I have several ignore statements in the .ini file but today replication stopped based of a sql statement that I thought should be ignored.  Ini and error below...can anyone see what I am doing wrong and the cleanest way to move forward past this error?

### error

Error 'Table 'registry_mobiledoc.regsitry_temp' doesn't exist' on query. Default database: 'mobiledoc'. Query: 'DELETE FROM registry_mobiledoc.regsitry_temp'

### config of slave

[mysqld]
basedir=E:/mysql
datadir=E:/mysql/data
tmpdir=E:/mysql/tmp

## log-bin=E:/mysql/mysql_binlogs/binarylogs

port=4928
skip-locking
skip-bdb
lower_case_table_names = 1
query_cache_type = 0
max_connections=300
query_cache_limit=1M
tmp_table_size=1M
max_tmp_tables=150
wait_timeout = 30
interactive_timeout = 30
table_cache = 900
flush_time = 0

## log-slow-queries

long_query_time=3
skip-name-resolve
expire_logs_days=14
server-id=3
default_table_type = INNODB

myisam_data_pointer_size=6

## If memory = 4GB

key_buffer = 256M

## max_allowed_packet = 1M

max_allowed_packet = 32M
sort_buffer_size = 512K
read_buffer_size = 512K
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 512M
query_cache_size = 0
tmp_table_size = 1M
thread_cache_size=250

## number of CPU's*2 for thread_concurrency

## The following parameter will change based on the number of CPUs. Some times

## the hyper threading is enabled which makes sinlge processor look like dual,

## so Make sure that this is done properly.

## For single processor -> 2

## Dual -> 4

## Quad -> 8

## thread_concurrency=2

## innodb_thread_concurrency=2

## Innodb parameters

innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=0
innodb_log_files_in_group=2
innodb_log_file_size=256M
transaction_isolation = REPEATABLE-READ
read_rnd_buffer_size = 8M

## innodb_data_home_dir=D:/eClinicalWorks/mysql/data

innodb_data_file_path = mobiledoc_InnoDb_data1:300M:autoextend
innodb_file_per_table
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size=8M

## configure innodb_buffer_pool_size according to available memory

innodb_buffer_pool_size=16G

innodb_log_buffer_size=8M

## set-variable=key_buffer=16M

innodb_data_home_dir=E:\mysql\data
master-host=192.168.12.83
master-user=SlaveUser
master-password=P@ssw0rd
master-port=4928
master-connect-retry=15
read-only=1
relay_log_purge

## replicate-wild-ignore-table=ecw%.measuretemp

## replicate-wild-ignore-table=ecw%.mu_%

## replicate-do-mobiledoc

replicate-ignore-db = cur_lmrp
replicate-ignore-db = ecwmaster
replicate-ignore-db = medispan
replicate-ignore-db = mysql
replicate-ignore-db = multum
replicate-ignore-db = registry_mobiledoc

skip-slave-start
slave-skip-errors=1062

[WinMySQLadmin]

## Server=D:/eClinicalWorks/mysql/bin/mysqld-nt.exe

user=root
password=test
Server=E:\mysql\mysql\mysqld-nt.exe